# Conexão do Visual Studio com um banco de dado Access

Tags: visual-studio

Tenho uma string de conexão com o banco de dados d Access:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\lentes.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Quando eu executo esse código sempre da o erro " Não há suporte para a palavra-chave 'Provider'."

PS. não tem nada depois desse código ainda, isso é tudo:

```
 string strcon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\lentes.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
```

ai eu executo o o try e catch pra ver o erro e da esse erro que eu falei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esta tentando criar uma conexão com o ACCESS usando o assembly **System.Data.SqlClient**.

Para o Acces, você obrigatoriamente vai ter que usar o assembly **System.Data.OleDbClient**

Aqui um exemplo de código:

```
public void ConnectToAccess()
{


  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new 
      System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        @"Data source= C:\Documents and Settings\username\" +
        @"My Documents\AccessFile.mdb";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: E tb não pode esquecer de retirar o `Provider=...;` da connection string

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Creio que neste caso o Provider seja obrigatório. A connetionstring para o OleDbClient exige o Provider. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbConnection_ConnectionString

Comment: Certo, William, é porque é OleDb, não tinha me tocado. Valeu!

Comment: Você acha que tem que instalar por fora o provedor OLE DB ou ele vem por padrão? Há uns 4 anos atrás, eu mexi com .accdb e tinha que instalar por fora

Comment: Download do provedor OLE DB Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB aqui: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: O Assembly System.Data.OleDBClient é nativo do .NET. O que talvez você tenha que instalar é o driver do Access, esse é a parte. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Valeu, William!